# Eigenvalues of a block off-diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

Let $A_1,A_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Construct the block matrix $A$ as follows:
$$A: = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{{A_1}}\\
{{A_2}}&0
\end{array}} \right]$$
My observation is that matrix $A$ cannot have all its eigenvalues in the open left-half plane. In other worlds, if all eigenvalues of $A$ have non-positive real parts, then all of them are imaginary.

I greatly appreciate it if someone can give me some idea/intuition why this happens.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is of the form $p(\lambda) = q(\lambda^2)$, where $q$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A_1A_2$. Therefore all roots come in pairs.

Comment: But, why can't we have complex conjugate roots (which are pairs) with negative real parts?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough there. I meant $\lambda$ is a root if and only if $-\lambda$ is a root.

Comment: I see. Thanks Klaus!