# How to block diagonalize a partitioned Hermitian matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I have a partitioned matrix ($2n \times 2n$) like this.
\begin{align}
\mathbf{M}= 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  \mathbf{X} & \mathbf{Y} \\
  \mathbf{Y^{\dagger}} & -\mathbf{X}
 \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

The matrices $X$ and $Y$ are $n\times n$ dimensional matrices. $\mathbf M$ is a Hermitian
matrix. Generally, it's very hard to solve the eigenvalue problem for $\mathbf M$ and get the exact expressions. If it were possible to block diagonalize the matrix like
\begin{align}
 \mathbf M = \mathbf m \oplus (-\mathbf m)
\end{align}
Then one could just solve the eigenvalue problem of $\mathbf m$ and found all the
eigenvalues of $\mathbf M$. For when $\mathbf X = \mathbf 0$ then the solution can be obtained using this method like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081327/)  . In my case, I have a diagonal matrix as my $\mathbf X$. I tried looking up diagonalization of partitioned matrices but I had no luck.

**Is there any way I can at least block diagonalize $\mathbf M$ ?**

Comment: Have you tried applying Schur complements? This would work only of X is invertible.

Comment: @Leo I tried to decompose the matrix in the LDU form. D is indeed a block diagonal matrix, but L and U are not unitary matrices so te D matrix doesn't have the same eigenvalues as M. That's what I think of it

Comment: I meant to use the equations here under the "Schur complement" heading. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant